# Special case of Polysemous

Tags: single-word-requests

I just read a paper which heavily used **polysemous**, which means (think like ancient Greeks: poly + meaning -> πολύ + σημασία -> πολύσημος -> polysemus, which *I think* is polysemous in plural, but polysemus is red-underlined, as not a word from my Mac.

However the paper use polysemous in place of "two meanings". That, in Greek, would result in δύο + σημασία -> disemous or maybe bisemous (you know, like bipolar means δι + πολικός -> δύο πόλους.

However both disemous and bisemous are ref-highlighted as wrong. After searching the Internet, I found *Is the word bisemous acceptable?* in [Chinese-forums](http://www.chinese-forums.com/index.php?/topic/40115-is-the-word-bisemous-acceptable/) and *bisemous* in [wordow](http://m.wordow.com/english/dictionary/?t=bisemous), which are a bit controversial, so I am heavily confused and I feel that these are not correct in English.

Is there a word (that follows the Greek root, thus the Latin, etc....) for two meanings? Like there is polysemous for many meanings.

Example:

> Pythia's oracles had two meanings.

Find `X` such that I can now say:

> Pythia's oracles were `X`.

---

<sub>Pythia was the "superstar" of The Oracle of Delphi in Ancient Greece. Her oracles were phrased in such a way that they were almost always correct, but the person that was asking for an oracle would interpret the oracle with the meaning that would be in its favor.</sub>

<sub>I clearly remember from school when one king (or leader) asked Pythia whether he should launch a massive attack to another Great Power of that times (imagine them like US vs Russia before some decades) and Pythia answered: Should you launch the attack, a great power will be vanished, or something like that, so that oracle was correct, because whoever would lose the war, would be "vanished", but both sides were great at that time.</sub>

Comment: Words with only a few meanings are often said to be *ambiguous*. Also, *bisemous* is fine (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bisemous). Don't trust your auto-correct.

Comment: Are often said *mistakenly* to be ambiguous? Oh then **bisemous** should serve as an answer. Shall you post one, please mention whether it is plural of not (if that applies). @Silenus ha that's true! :)

Comment: By the way *monosymous*, *bisemous*, and *polysemous* are all adjectives. As such, they are neither singular nor plural.

Comment: Yeah @Silenus that's why I said if applies. I just asked however, since in Greek you would distinguish πολύσημος from πολύσημοι, given the following/pair word. For example, I would say polysemos oracle (in Greek) and polysemous oracles. But that's not the case in English, as far as I can see, but thanks for pointing that out, really!

Comment: *Mono-* and *poly-* are Greek prefixes, so for a prefix in the same series meaning *two* you would need *di-.* But I favor *ambiguous* as better established and as meaning capable of being interpreted in *two* distinct ways. So no, gsamaras, that is *not* a mistaken usage.

Comment: Oh, and I think you mean *vanquished* not *vanished,* and *"should* you launch the attack."

Comment: Thanks @BrianDonovan. Well I think no, she has said that the one side would not just lose, but being overtaken thoroughly, but you know better for sure, so just go ahead and edit if you like. I am not sure what the difference between the shall and should is here.

Comment: Even if the καταλύω of [Herodotus 1.53.3](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0126%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D53%3Asection%3D3) and [Aristotle *Rhetoric* 3.5](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0060%3Abook%3D3%3Achapter%3D5) and the καταπαύω of [Herodotus 1.86.1](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0126%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D86%3Asection%3D1) mean more than merely *vanquish,* *vanish* is not a transitive verb in English and thus has no passive.

Comment: And *should* is needed as a conditional form for a conditional sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Bisemous*** is fine, but let me argue for it.

First, consider that ***[monosemy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/monosemy?q=monosemous#monosemy__6)*** (and ***monosemous***) is recognized by Oxford Dictionary as:

> *Linguistics*
>
> The property of having only one meaning.

Next, consider that ***[polysemy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/polysemy?q=polysemous#polysemy__8)*** (and ***polysemous***) is also recognized by Oxford Dictionary as:

> *Linguistics*
>
> The coexistence of many possible meanings for a word or phrase.

While *bisemous* is not recognized by Oxford, it is easily formed and understood on analogy with *monosemous* and *polysemous*.

Wiktionary even has an entry on ***[bisemous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bisemous)***:

> (*linguistics*)
>
> Having two meanings or interpretations.

Now, some might object that *bi-* is Latin, not Greek like *mono-* and *poly-*. But I would argue that *bi-* is more easily understood as "two" than the Greek equivalent *di-*. Further, I personally have encountered *bisemous* more than *disemous*, although there *are* [occurrences](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=disemous) of the latter.

The fact that your spellchecker doesn't recognize it should not deter you from using it.

Answer (score -1):

Ambiguous doesn't cut it because it usually implies potential to be misunderstood.  Bisemous is necessary when the intention is to communicate two ideas from the same concept.

Such a word is useful in Biblical hermeneutics.  Polyvalent for many meanings is a possibility but is usually a more specialised scientific term.   If polysemous is specialised for linguistics, we really could do with something better for general usage.

And if it were prefixed with poly-, we could have a bi- and mono- version as well.  In the meantime, I am going to have to append -semous and rely on context for my meaning to be clear.

Comment: Did you read the other answer? It shows that there are dictionary entries for all three, so bi- and mono- are not speculations.

Comment: Merriam-Webster gives two senses of [ambiguous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambiguous): "doubtful or uncertain especially from obscurity or indistinctness" which is the sense you say, and "capable of being understood in two or more possible senses or ways", which is the sense the OP wants.